# Get video by ajax with wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I want to get video in a modal by ajax. I get this video from a custom field in Wordpress. My code is working on localhost, and on the server.It stopped working without any changes on the server, and return 0.There is no any error in the console.

Although it still works well on localhost.

**Below is function.php.**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getTheVideo', 'getTheVideo');
add_action('wp_ajax_getTheVideo', 'getTheVideo');

function getTheVideo(){
  $args = array('post_type' => 'page');
  query_posts($args);
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if( have_rows('builder_page') ){
      while ( have_rows('builder_page') ) : the_row();
        if( get_row_layout() == 'introduction_section' ){
        $full_video = get_sub_field('full_video', get_the_ID());
        $upload_full_video = $full_video['upload_full_video'];

        if($upload_full_video) {

        $modal = "<video playsinline controls>
                    <source src=" . $upload_full_video['url'] . " type='video/mp4'>
                  </video>";

        echo $modal;

        die();
      }else{
        echo "<div class='text-center p-4'><h2> Sorry ! No Video :( </h2> 
             </div>";
      }
    }
    endwhile;
   }
 endwhile;
}
```

**Below is ajax code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#showModal').on('click' , function(){
  $.ajax({
    url : v_Ajax.ajax_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {action:'getTheVideo'},
    success : function (response) {
      $('#resData').html(response);
    },
    error : function(){
      $('#resData').html("<div class='text-center p-4'><h2> Sorry ! No Video :( </h2></div>");
    },
  });
  });
});
```